# How to select data from 1 to 5 days with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I've tried it here but I could not, I can only display the total.

I have a download table and a program table.

Every time I download a program I record the date and time, I need to do a grouping of downloaded programs and then 5 columns with the dates, here's an example.

```
PROGRAMA   |  HOJE  | ONTEM| 2 DIAS | 3 DIAS | 4 DIAS

Programa 1     11      110     55       66      12  
Programa 2     25      140     60       90      12
Programa 3     10      20      20       10      10  
TOTAL          46      270     135      166     32
```

**Below is my query**

```
select `k`.`app_id` AS `app_id`,`b`.`aplicativo` AS `aplicativo`,count(0) AS `HOJE`,

(select count(0) AS `count(*)` from (`registration` `a` join `aplicativos` `b`) where `k`.`app_id`= `b`.`id`    and created_at  > (cast(now() as date) - interval 1 day) and (`a`.`created_at` < cast(now() as date)- interval 0 day) ) as ONTEM ,

(select count(0) AS `count(*)` from (`registration` `a` join `aplicativos` `b`) where `k`.`app_id` = `b`.`id`
 and created_at  > (cast(now() as date) - interval 2 day) and (`a`.`created_at` < cast(now() as date)- interval 1 day) ) as 2_DIAS_ANTES ,

(select count(0) AS `count(*)` from (`registration` `a` join `aplicativos` `b`) where `k`.`app_id` = `b`.`id`
 and created_at  > (cast(now() as date) - interval 3 day) and (`a`.`created_at` < cast(now() as date)- interval 2 day) ) as 3_DIAS_ANTES ,

(select count(0) AS `count(*)` from (`registration` `a` join `aplicativos` `b`) where `k`.`app_id` = `b`.`id`
 and created_at  > (cast(now() as date) - interval 4 day) and (`a`.`created_at` < cast(now() as date)- interval 3 day) ) as 4_DIAS_ANTES ,

(select count(0) AS `count(*)` from (`registration` `a` join `aplicativos` `b`) where `k`.`app_id` = `b`.`id`
 and created_at  > (cast(now() as date) - interval 5 day) and (`a`.`created_at` < cast(now() as date)- interval 4 day) ) as 5_DIAS_ANTES 


from (`registration` `k` join `aplicativos` `b`) where ((`k`.`app_id` = `b`.`id`) and (`k`.`created_at` > (cast(now() as date) - interval 0 day)))

group by `b`.`aplicativo`
```

**Table structure**

**Table aplicativos**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aplicativos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aplicativo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `quantidade_notificacoes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

**Table registration**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gcm_regid` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=73876 ;
```

Comment: ¿Could you post the table structure?

Comment: Hello friend, I posted the structure, if you need anything else let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach for MySQL:

```
SELECT a.aplicativo as PROGRAMA,
      sum(Date(r.created_at) = CURDATE()) AS HOJE,
      sum(date(r.created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0)) AS ONTEM,
       ...
FROM registration r INNER JOIN 
     aplicativos a
     on r.app_id = a.id
GROUP BY r.app_id ;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff, PERFECT! It worked. Do you know how I can put the day of the week in each column? Example yesterday was Friday display in column Friday?

Comment: I tried this way -, date_format (CURDATE () - 1, '% d-% m at% Hh% i')
   But it gives error

Comment: @William . . . I don't know what you mean by including the day of the week.  Can you ask another question with sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you the expected result?

```
SELECT 
a.aplicativo as PROGRAMA,
COUNT(IF(DATE(r.created_at) = CURDATE(), 1, 0)) AS HOJE,
COUNT(IF(DATE(r.created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0)) AS ONTEM,
COUNT(IF(DATE(r.created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), 1, 0)) AS 2DIAS,
COUNT(IF(DATE(r.created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), 1, 0)) AS 3DIAS,
COUNT(IF(DATE(r.created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), 1, 0)) AS 4DIAS,
COUNT(IF(DATE(r.created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY), 1, 0)) AS 5DIAS
FROM registration r
INNER JOIN aplicativos a
ON r.app_id = a.id
GROUP BY r.app_id, DATE(r.created_at) with ROLLUP;
```

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(r.created_at) GROUP BY r.app_id with ROLLUP LIMIT 0, 100'

Comment: Even removing the "DATE (r.created_at)" query continues with the duplicate data on days.
Each day has a different total per program

Comment: James_Bons, thanks for the help but your query doubled everything. I used our friend @Gordon Linoff  and it worked out